# lightning:buttonMenu value not coming in controller

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura, lightning-buttonmenu

I am using lightningmenu item in an aura iteration

```
event.detail.menuItem.get("v.value");
```

Compoennt Code

```
 <lightning:buttonMenu iconName="utility:down" onselect="{!c.onButtonMenuSelect}" alternativeText="Show menu" class="{!financialAccountRecord.Id}">
                        <lightning:menuItem value="edit" label="Edit"/>
```

Controller Code:

```
   onButtonMenuSelect: function(component, event, helper) {
    var idx = event.detail.menuItem("value"));
    switch (event.getParam("value")){
        case "edit": helper.doEdit(); break;
        case "delete": helper.doDelete(); break;
    }
}
```

Howvere the value of idx is coming as undefined. I also tried the following variations:

```
({
  handleSelect: function(component, event, helper) {
    switch event.get("value") {
      case "edit": helper.doEdit(); break;
      case "edit": helper.doDelete(); break;
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

First use `event.getSource()` to get the menu component, then `.get("v.value")` to get the current menu item that was selected.

Try this for the controller code:

```
onButtonMenuSelect: function(component, event, helper) {
    switch (event.getSource().get("v.value")){
        case "edit": helper.doEdit(); break;
        case "delete": helper.doDelete(); break;
    }
}
```